# Reading out a Json using java static error

Tags: java, json, filereader

I want to load a json gfile with java and store the data in variables

I've tried this but it always gives an error

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.*
...

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("/opt/step-agent/conf/conf_internet_explorer.json"))
        {
            Object obj = JsonParser.parse(reader);
            JsonObject config = (JsonObject) obj;
            String driverPath = config.get("driverPath").getAsString();
            String HttpProxy = config.get("HttpProxy").getAsString();
            String SslProxy = config.get("SslProxy").getAsString();
            boolean proxy = (boolean) config.get("proxy");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the json

```
{
    "config": {
        "driverPath":"path/to/driver",
        "proxy":true,
        "HttpProxy":"http://proxy.local:80",
        "SslProxy":"http://proxy.local:80",
    }
}
```

the error:

```
non-static method parse(java.io.Reader) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up your var with the Class.

You should write

`Object obj = parser.parse(reader);`

`parser` is your var which contains a `Instance of JsonParser` which has the method `parse()`

instead of

`Object obj = JsonParser.parse(reader);`

`JsonParser` is the `Class JsonParser` which has no static method `parse()`